# NHibernate Many-to-Many Mapping not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I have a Nhibernate mapping file for a simple user/role mapping.

Here are the mapping files:

**Users.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Sample.Persistence" namespace="Sample.Persistence.Model">
    <class name="User" table="Users">
        <id name="UserKey">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <property name="UserName" column="UserName" type="String" />
        <property name="Password" column="Password" type="Byte[]" />

        <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" type="String" />
        <property name="LastName" column="LastName" type="String" />
        <property name="Email" column="Email" type="String" />

        <property name="Active" column="Active" type="Boolean" />
        <property name="Locked" column="Locked" type="Boolean" />

        <property name="LoginFailures" column="LoginFailures" type="int" />
        <property name="LockoutDate" column="LockoutDate" type="DateTime" generated="insert" />

        <property name="Expired" column="Expired" type="Boolean" generated="insert"/>

        <set name="Roles" table="UsersRolesBridge"   lazy="false">
            <key column="UserKey" />
            <many-to-many class="Role"
            not-found="exception"
            column="RoleKey" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Role.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Sample.Persistence" namespace="Sample.Persistence.Model">
    <class name="Role" table="Roles">
        <id name="RoleKey">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" />

        <set name="Users" inverse="true" table="UsersRolesBridge" lazy="false" >
            <key column="RoleKey" />
            <many-to-many class="User" column="UserKey" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am able to retrieve roles for each user via NHibernate but when I go to save a new object, the roles are not saved in the Bridge table.

The user is created and insert with no issues. I've checked that the Role collection, a field on the user, is being populated with the proper rolekey before the Session.Save() is called.

There is no exception thrown as well.

UPDATE:

After adding a cascade, there was still no actual insert taking place to the M-2-M table.

The logs from Nhibernate showed the following:

```
12/22/2010 23:18:11.684 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for: Sample.Persistence.Model.User
Exception: 

12/22/2010 23:18:11.686 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: done processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for: Sample.Persistence.Model.User
Exception: 

12/22/2010 23:18:11.789 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for: Sample.Persistence.Model.User
Exception: 

12/22/2010 23:18:11.792 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for collection: Sample.Persistence.Model.User.Roles
Exception: 

12/22/2010 23:18:11.814 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: done cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for collection: Sample.Persistence.Model.User.Roles
Exception: 

12/22/2010 23:18:11.814 [11] INFO  NHibernate.Engine.Cascade 
Message: done processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for: Sample.Persistence.Model.User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a cascade on the relationship. By default, inserts, updates, and deletes are not cascaded. More information here:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/nhibernatecascadesthedifferentbetweenallalldeleteorphansandsaveupdate.aspx

Comment: Both yours and lonmaxx's worked. 
There was two issues as well relating to the session(it was closing too early) and that it wasn't wrapped in a transaction. 

I'm now dealing with an error where it tries to update the ROLE table, despite have inverse setup. May need to ask another question.

Comment: Inverse means update the relationship table from the other side. The save will still cascade to the contained objects. I don't know of an easy way to only cascade the relationship, but not changes to the child objects. Best asked as another question so others can provide their input.

Answer (score 2):

I generally find that many to many issues are caused by not setting the cascade properties properly.

Try setting the cascade = "save-update" attribute on the Roles set in the Users.hbm.xml file

```
<set name="Roles" table="UsersRolesBridge"   lazy="false" cascade="save-update">
```